# WTAI - wtai://wp/ap;07773363222. Add more contact information using this method

Tags: html, mobile, href, addressbook, wtai

I have stumbled across a neat piece of code which adds a phone number directly to an address book:

```
<href="wtai://wp/ap;07773363893>TEXT</a>
```

Is there anyway we can add more information using this method such as name, email address etc?

I wish to use this method just because of the sheer simplicity and ease. Click, Add, Save. If there are any other solutions you would recommend I would love to hear from you.

Any and all help would be hugely appreciated and if I can do anything more to articulate my question and increase its understandability just let me know. Thank you!

Comment: does this url scheme actually still work on any contemporary devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add the name using this functionality:

```
wtai://wp/ap;number;name
```

I'm not sure it's possible for other information such as e-mail address. I imagine this is because name will be used on every contact for every phone whereas other Mobile Operating Systems might not necessarily have the option for this information.

In response to the comments below you may enter:

```
wtai://wp/ap;number;firstName lastName
```

However, I'm not sure how that maps on devices. I know of instances where only the `lastName` is picked up

Comment: Thanks so the name part populates the first name section. How about surname?

Comment: Or is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Thanks that worked great. Shame about the email address etc but never mind