# How can I link telephone number in browser to save contact on mobile

Tags: php, android, ios, mobile

I was wondering if it is possible from a mobile browser to click on a telephone number which will then open the 'Add a new contact' option. I have seen snippets of code for click to call but I was wondering if there is a way to do this for saving contacts.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.taboil.com/%D7%98%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%20%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C.vcf
```

create a link like this
it will  prompt on mobile to save contact

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED- 
PRINTABLE:=D7=93=D7=95=D7=93=D7=95=20=D7=97=D7=9E;;;;
FN;CHARSET=UTF-8;ENCODING=QUOTED- 
PRINTABLE:=D7=93=D7=95=D7=93=D7=95=20=D7=97=D7=9E
TEL;CELL:0555555555
TEL;VOICE:059555555
END:VCARD
```

this is the content of the vcf file

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
var = "+97239222222";
window.location = "wtai://wp/ap;" + waNumber + ";z1";
```

[WTAI - wtai://wp/ap;07773363222. Add more contact information using this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212255/wtai-wtai-wp-ap07773363222-add-more-contact-information-using-this-method)

Comment: How are you implementing this? How can I connect this snippet of code to a link to save the details?